# Data.Text.Lazy.Builder vs Text.Builder

Tags: performance, haskell, text

What is a difference between module `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder` ([text package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html)) and module `Text.Builder` ([text-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-builder-0.6.4/docs/Text-Builder.html))? I mean the goals, efficiency and possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used `text-builder` but it purports to be an "An efficient *strict text* builder" (emphasis mine), while the standard `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder` builds lazy `Text` (essentially a linked list of UTF-16 array chunks). The point of both libraries (the idea of a `Builder`), is to avoid a bunch of allocation and copying as you accumulate a string by appending.

It looks to me like the `text-builder` library mostly restricts itself to types with a statically known size. I suppose its reason for existing is this could be made more efficient than the normal builder in `text`; in `run` you can allocate just once and then serialize into the array, where in `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder` you might need to grow or allocate new chunks as you go. And if what you really need is a strict `Text` then you'll probably need to pay for copying all those chunks anyway (and that might also involve additional copying of intermediate strict `Text` too, I'm not sure).

But this is mostly speculation. Maybe Nikita Volkov will chime in.

Comment: I confirm everything said :) The benchmarks that the source code of "text-builder" package comes with show that it is faster at least in the covered cases. There also are success story user reports, e.g., [this one](https://twitter.com/thumphriees/status/924882781406035968).